# how to convert a string to timestamp in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

i have a string "Fri Nov  3 17:50:23 2017"  like this

how to convert this String to Timestamp(2017-11-03T17:50:23)  using shell script in Linux

Please help me. 
sagar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date --date='Fri Nov 3 17:50:23 2017' +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

p.s. if 'T' is not typo in your desired output, just change space with 'T'

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
#Declare
zero=0
Time_S=T
Jan=1
Feb=2
Mar=3
Nov=11
     string="Fri Nov 3 17:50:23 2017"
     s1=$(echo $string|cut -d " " -f5)
     s2=$(echo $string|cut -d " " -f2)
     s3=$(echo $string|cut -d " " -f3)
     s4=$Time_S$(echo $string|cut -d " " -f4)
     if [ $s3 -lt 10 ];then
        echo "valuse is less than 10"
         s3=$zero$s3
    else
        s3=$(($s3))
    fi
     echo "$s1-$(($s2))-$s3$s4"
```